# Capture RRC state log in android

Tags: android, networking, logging

I am trying to capture RRC state logs which change time to time in mobile devices based on network usage .As of now the only way possible is to run special codes E.g "*#0011#" from dialer which is an inbuilt feature of device and cannot be run as a service in background.
Assuming i know the code to turn RCC state capture on, how can i log this in background in a file ?

Also is there anyway to capture and store logs that come up in adb logcat even when device is not connected to a computer ? assuming device keeps generating similar logs even when not connected to android adb shell.